# Sending PDF Attachment Using Twilio Whatsapp API (PHP)

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-php

I am trying to send PDF document using Twilio Whatsapp API.While Using MediaURL ,If I make my document as public only,it will work otherwise it won't work.Can you tell me Solution to attachment document(PDF) without make it public access.

Tried to attach PDF using MediaUrl , It won't if my document not in public access.

I want solution to attach PDF document using Twilio Whatsapp API(PHP) without make document public access.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way WhatsApp Business API is designed, it's not currently possible to send a private PDF document using `mediaUrl`. The document has to be publicly accessible on the internet. This is because WhatsApp needs to download the media file from the URL you provide, and if it's private or requires authentication, WhatsApp might not be able to access it.

However, you do have some control over when and how your document is shared. Once your WhatsApp message is sent and delivered, which usually only takes a few seconds, you can then remove the document from public access, limiting the window of time it's publicly available.